# ARM Cortex M0+ unexplained Hard Fault exception

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm working with the Rasberry PI Pico RP2040 with ARM Cortex M0+.
Writing some assembler glue code for some c-code.

I'm getting an unexplained Hard Fault exception when trying to push a few registers on to the stack.

The stack pointer (MSP) has just been loaded with 0x20001630 and it is pointing to writeable memory at that location and below, the stack is correctly aligned etc.

When the processor executes the push instruction it results in a Hard Fault exception.

Here is the code with the register contents when the core is trying to execute the push.

```
r0             0x200015e0
r1             0x7200
r2             0x7000
r3             0x20001630
r4             0x20007840
r5             0x20001bd8
r6             0x18000000 
r7             0x200015e8
sp             0x20001630
lr             0x10000489
pc             0x1000048e
xPSR           0x01000000
msp            0x20001630
psp            0x20042000
primask        0x0 
basepri        0x0 
faultmask      0x0 
control        0x0 

    ldr     r3, =alternate   // first word of alternate has new stack pointer
    ldr     r3, [r3]         // r3 contains the new stack pointer
    mov     sp, r3           // sp assigned to new stack
--> push    {r0-r3}          // HardFault
```

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.